# Is there an existing library for converting ArcGIS Features to Json?

Tags: arcobjects, geojson

Is there an existing library for converting ArcGIS IFeature types to and from Json/GeoJson?

Comment: For featureset to json Esri and json Esri to featureset you can see my post http://nicogis.blogspot.it/2012/04/json-arcobjects.html

Answer (score 6):

You should check out GeoJSON.Net by Vish: http://viswaug.wordpress.com/2008/05/11/geojsonnet-a-net-library-to-produce-geojson-output/

It should be pretty easy to extend it to use ArcObjects geometries.

Also, you can take a look at the GeoJSON exporter I did for SharpMap (you'll have to Google that since StackExchange won't let me post a second hyperlink). The geometry objects in SharpMap have a very similar structure to those in ArcObjects so that should be pretty easy to extend as well.

Comment: A lot of good pointers there, but like most other options, I'd have to write my own implementation, which is the route I've gone.

Answer (score 6):

ArcGIS 10 has the [`AsShape`](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#/AsShape/000v00000153000000/) function for converting GeoJSON to arcpy geometries, which mimics [Shapely](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/Shapely/)'s `AsShape`, and arcpy geometry objects implement the `__geo_interface__` standard (also from Shapely) for getting arcpy geometries back as GeoJSON.

Comment: While this is a good time, I'd have liked them to use a similar idea to the IXMLSerializer interface, but with Json.  More consistent, and available in all languages which can use ArcObjects.

Comment: You could roll your own in ArcGIS 10 with IJSONWriter and the JSONWriter CoClass: http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/Arcobjects_CPP/componenthelp/index.html#//001n00000108000000

Comment: arcpy's AsShape/__geo_interface__ is handy but just don't pass in any polygons with interior rings: http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/10201/arcpy-geometry-geo-interface-and-asshape-function-loss-of-precision-and-h

Answer (score 1):

This question with answer from Stack Overflow may work.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2223979/convert-a-shapefile-shp-to-xml-json

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.  Sadly the library referenced reads shapefiles natively, rather than using the ArcObjects framework.

Answer (score 1):

Your best bet is to write your own framework. Use arcobjects so you can use geometries stored in any kind of geodatabase/shapefile/coverage. It shouldn't be too hard to do it.

Comment: It's fairly easy to write one for simple geometries, less so when you need to support the more exotic cases.  This is however the route I've gone.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see any existing library, but [this C# REST interface](http://svn2.assembla.com/svn/arcdeveloper/ArcDeveloper.REST/trunk/Product/Production/ArcDeveloper.REST.Formatters.GeoJSON/) from ArcDeveloper  provides a start. There's also this CC-AO licensed [Python toolbox to export a feature class to GeoJSON](http://arcscripts.esri.com/details.asp?dbid=15545) which should fit the bill, it handles the five major vector types.

The [GeoJSON spec](http://geojson.org/geojson-spec.html) is straightforward and shouldn't be too onerous to implement, if the toolbox doesn't meet your needs.

Comment: Sadly the python option, while it fits the bill, needs to be used in a server context, where using the geoprocessing object creates threading and scaling issues.

Answer (score 0):

ESRI has this free Python script that converts from feature class to json, geojson or csv. [esri2open](https://github.com/project-open-data/esri2open)

Answer (score 0):

A bit of a late addition, but figured it's a useful addition...

I use [ArcGIS.PCL](https://github.com/davetimmins/ArcGIS.PCL) which works very well. Allows you to interact with ArcGIS and spit out any of the geometries as GeoJson.