# arcpy.geometry __geo_interface__ and AsShape() function: loss of precision and holes

Tags: arcpy, geojson, attributeerror

I'm serializing my arcpy geometries as geojson so that I can 'hydrate' them back as geometries later and I'm having 2 problems in the cycle.:

**PROBLEM 1: Precision**

```
    R0 = arcpy.SearchCursor(self.shpTest, "FID=0").next().getValue("Shape")          
    geojson = R0.__geo_interface__                        
    R1 = arcpy.AsShape(geojson)
    self.assertTrue(R0.equals(R1)) <<< THIS FAILS
```

If I check the string representation, the coordinates have slightly changed:

```
    geojson2 = R1.__geo_interface__
    print geojson
    print geojson2  

    {'type': 'Polygon', 'coordinates': [[(442343.5516410945, 4814166.6184399202), (442772.17749834526, 4811610.7383281607), (441565.67508534156, 4811499.6131059099), (440772.50052100699, 4814184.7808806188), (442343.5516410945, 4814166.6184399202)]]}
    {'type': 'Polygon', 'coordinates': [[(442343.55169677734, 4814166.6185302734), (442772.17749023438, 4811610.73828125), (441565.67510986328, 4811499.6130981445), (440772.50048828125, 4814184.7808837891), (442343.55169677734, 4814166.6185302734)]]}
```

**PROBLEM 2: Holes**
If the polygon has holes, **geo_interface** generates an error:

```
    R0_WithHoles = arcpy.SearchCursor(self.shpTest, "FID=0").next().getValue("Shape")          
    geojson = R0.__geo_interface__  <<< generates this ERROR:

    File "C:\Program Files\ArcGIS\Desktop10.0\arcpy\arcpy\arcobjects\geometries.py", line 68, in __geo_interface__
        return {'type': 'Polygon', 'coordinates': [[(pt.X, pt.Y) for pt in part] for part in self]}
    AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'X'
```

Any ideas on how to solve these problems?

Comment: Yep, just ran across number 2 myself. And doesn't appear to be much love for this topic.

Comment: This is still broken in arcpy in ArcGIS 10.1 -- It would be nice if ESRI could comment on the subject.

Comment: I came across the first and second problems. With me, the coordinated do not seem to change (when you print them) but geom1.equals(geom2) fails me only a few times. I am not sure why that happens as well. The 2nd problem was fixed using @valveLondon 's suggestion. If you found out how to fix the .equals please do share.

Comment: @MichalisAvraam We had the same issue also and got onto ESRI for a solution - turns out it's a known bug (when you create a geom without a projection it truncates the precision) - take a look at [this question](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/37635/how-to-draw-shapes-with-highest-possible-decimal-accuracy/37681) also.

Comment: @om_henners I assumed that. But the arcpy.AsShape() function does not let you specify a spatial reference. I have set all environment variables hoping it would do something (output coords, etc...). The solution then is to manually decode the GeoJSON because ESRI doesn't care about accuracy?

Comment: @MichalisAvraam Afraid so. Not sure about 10.1, but ESRI have said they're not going to fix it for 10. If it helps I've got a script that I've just put up on [gist.github](https://gist.github.com/4062925) that you might be able to strip for relavent bits.

Comment: @om_henners Thank you. I wound up rewriting the AsShape function in geometries.py, but ended up not using it and switching to ogr to handle geometries. But this is incredibly helpful. Thank you so much for sharing. Hopefully others can see this too.

Answer (score 5):

OK - well I thought I had solved it.

replace line ~80 of this file C:\Python26\ArcGIS10.0\Lib\arcpy\arcobjects\geometries.py
from this:

```
return {'type': 'Polygon', 'coordinates': [[(pt.X, pt.Y) for pt in part] for part in self]}
```

to this (or something that is more concise and elegant and does the same thing):

```
  obj = {"type": "Polygon"}
    coordinates = []
    for part in self:
        _part = []
        for pt in part:
            if pt is not None:
                print pt
                _part.append([pt.X,pt.Y])
            else:
                print "none"
                coordinates.append(_part)
                _part=[]
        coordinates.append(_part)
    obj["coordinates"]=coordinates
    return obj
```

Basically they forgot to consider donuts in the shape which are marked by null point values.  This spits out good geoJson (separate parts) but the arcpy.AsShape method trashes GeoJSON.

this code:

```
import arcpy
gj = {
  'type': 'Polygon', 'coordinates': [
   [[-122.803764, 45.509158], [-122.796246, 45.500050], [-122.808193, 45.500109],
      [-122.803764, 45.509158]],
   [[-122.804206, 45.504509], [-122.802882, 45.502522], [-122.801866, 45.504479], 
      [-122.804206, 45.504509]]
   ]
 }

 p = arcpy.AsShape(gj)
 print p.__geo_interface__
```

outputs this:

```
    {'type': 'Polygon', 'coordinates': [[[-122.8037109375, 45.50927734375],  
    [-122.79620361328125, 45.5001220703125], [-122.80810546875, 45.5001220703125],
    [-122.8037109375, 45.50927734375]]]}
```

I give up. ;)

**Update**
The holes problem has been solved at 10.1 with this chunk of python:

```
return {'type': 'Polygon', 'coordinates': [[((pt.X, pt.Y) if pt else None)
                                                    for pt in part]
                                                        for part in self]}
```

Comment: shouldn't that return a dictionary instead of a string representing a dictionary? :)

Comment: Yes, you're right, it should.  I changed it to spit out a valid GeoJSON dictionary obj.  but after checking against the AsShape method I realized the futility of my efforts.

Comment: I wonder if that has anything to do with the problem described in this thread: http://forums.arcgis.com/threads/9763-Errors-in-arcpy-s-Polygon-class -- should have been fixed in 10 SP2 and definitely 10.1.

Comment: Yah - that looks like a pretty solid thread.  I just put SP4 on and .. no love.

Comment: @valveLondon- Did Esri update their master code for geometries.py in 10.1 so that it now works "out of the box"? Or does the user still have to change the chunk of code on their own?

Comment: ESRI updated `C:\Program Files\ArcGIS\Server\arcpy\arcpy\arcobjects\geometries.py` at 10.1 but if you're at 10.0 you can fix it yourself.

Comment: Yes, I fixed it in 10.1, the update above is the new source in the `.py` file. I thought it made it into a service pack for 10 but I guess not.

Comment: Still hope for SP5, chin up Jason!

Comment: @valveLondon   Unfortunately that breaks the Polygon class in 10.0 (the _fromGeoJson gives an error when called from arcpy.AsShape() because it cannot handle None types). Do you mind copy/pasting that part too? The return statement. Now it is return cls(Array([map(lambda p: Point(*p), part) for part in coordinates]))

Comment: @valveLondon   My solution follows: `return cls(Array([map(lambda p: Point(*p) if p is not None else Point(), part) for part in coordinates]))`. I hope it is as efficient as the potential ESRI solution.

Comment: @JasonScheirer- Do you know if the fix made it into 10SP5? And if the change I have in my comment would solve the AsShape part of the geometries.py file?