# Drawing shapes with highest possible decimal accuracy

Tags: arcpy, polygon, point

I am trying to read input of lat and long to draw the shape based on condition.The input is standard array of lat and long with 15 decimal accuracy. I am realizing - I am loosing some decimal accuracy (the point was somewhat offsite and complex polygons were never drawn). 
The samples are here:

point: [[[-81.00392112682097,46.50255058560673]]]

the plotted point is: -81.003906    46.502686 and I am generating PDF maps at 1:3000 scale so it is a big deal.

polygon: [[[-79.37485174735863,43.6430783790403],[-79.37361793121188,43.64341222822559],[-79.37323169311376,43.64261253986735],[-79.374186559523,43.64234079868168],[-79.37412218650664,43.64220880966229],[-79.37454061111293,43.64210787668709],[-79.37471227248987,43.64248831547784],[-79.37463717063745,43.64251160757044],[-79.37481956085045,43.64285322389105],[-79.37470154365381,43.642884279823875],[-79.37485174735863,43.6430783790403]]]

I used eval to read input as list, but probably that was not a good idea. Not sure how and where should I cast the input as decimal?

```
OrderCoord =  eval(arcpy.GetParameterAsText(0))
point = arcpy.Point()
array = arcpy.Array()
 # A list that will hold each of the Polygon objects 
featureList = []
for feature in OrderCoord:
    # For each coordinate pair, set the x,y properties and add to the 
    #  Array object.
    #
    for coordPair in feature:
        point.X = coordPair[0]
        point.Y = coordPair[1]
        array.add(point)

    if OrderType.lower()== 'point':
    feaERIS = arcpy.Multipoint(array)
    elif OrderType.lower() =='polyline':
    feaERIS  = arcpy.Polyline(array)    
    else :
    feaERIS = arcpy.Polygon(array)
    # Clear the array for future use
    array.removeAll()

    # Append to the list of Polygon objects
    featureList.append(feaERIS)
```

I added the screenshot of these points at 2000 scales. We have a Flex application where customer can draw and order a geometry. All the data sits in ORACLE and I am working on a GP Tool to print final PDF. 
[image: I added the screenshot of these points at 2000 scales. We have a Flex application where customer can draw and order a geometry. All the data sits in ORACLE and I am working on a GP Tool to print final PDF.]

Comment: No sure why you need 15 d.p. for lat/lng 6 is usually suffice.  see http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//003n0000001v000000

Comment: for the point: [[[-81.00392112682097,46.50255058560673]]]      the plotted point is: -81.003906 46.502686 (apparently it is not accurate even for 4th decimal) and I am generating PDF maps at 1:3000 scale so it is a big deal.

Comment: You should work from a Scale that is larger than 3000 - say 1:2000 then reduce the plot to 1:3000 maintaining accuracy.

Comment: Try setting the spatial reference on the featureclass if it's not set. You may even need to customize its xy resolution, but for a geographic coordinate system, the default xy resolution is around 10e-9 which is less than a mm.

Comment: @Mapperz, 6 decimal places in degrees is about 0.3 m or 1 ft. I usually recommend at least 8 for the resolution/storage. The xy tolerance value can be larger. (removed earlier comment which left out "8". oops)

Comment: The sixth decimal place represents no more than 0.11m: see http://gis.stackexchange.com/a/8674. The error is at most half that.  At 1:3000 scale that's a precision of (1/2)/33000 m, or about 1/66 mm--it's less than one-tenth the diameter of a typical human hair.  It's the width of one half of one pixel in hardcopy printed at 800 dpi. That's more than enough precision for any map.

Comment: I agree with whuber! who couldn't with an answer that precise. @user8732 what are you using to return the coordinate. I know that arcmap won't "show" you more than 6 decimals by default. Whatever you are using may be the limit. ??

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Turns out its a known bug in ArcGIS (which is not a priority to be fixed sadly). We had the same issue ourselves when trying to input features using `arcpy.AsShape`. From the ESRI tech support response we got it turns out that if you don't specify a spatial reference ArcGIS automatically truncates data to 3 decimal places. This remains the case even if you try and specify the tolerance using `arcpy.env.XYTolerance`.

The only solution is to create the geometry object with a spatial reference. For example the [`arcpy.Polygon`](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#/Polygon/000v000000n1000000/) object takes a [Spatial Reference](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#/SpatialReference/000v000000p6000000/) object as it's second argument.

Note that [`arcpy.Point`](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#/Point/000v000000mv000000/) is used to construct geometries, but is not a [point geometry](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#/PointGeometry/000v000000n0000000/) itself. `arcpy.Point` does store the full resolution of the point until it's used to create a geometry and doesn't take a spatial reference argument itself.