# "Polygon With Hole" gives a 'NoneType' error when assigning it to a shapely shape in Python

Tags: polygon, shapely

I am using Python and shapely to do certain spatial calculations (difference, intersections etc).

Bur before I can do the calculations I first need to get the object into a shapely object.
so I iterate through the shapes in a feature class using arcpy.da.searchcursor:

```
with arcpy.da.SearchCursor(OurCADLAYER, ['SHAPE@'], whereclause) as onerows:
        for onerow in onerows:
```

and then assign the shapely object here:

```
            Shape2 = shape(onerow[0])
```

and this is where I get the error message:
TypeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute getitem

PS. THIS ONLY HAPPENS when the shape is a Polygon that has holes (interior rings). no issues with normal polygons..

Comment: Passing an Esri Shape object into another software implementation  is a huge leap of faith.  I'd recommend using Well -Known Text or Binary. What calculations are you doing that ArcPy doesn't support?

Comment: ArcPy has all the necessary calculations, but I am getting errors, for example: I am trying to use the difference method: ShapeDiff = Shape1.difference(Shape2) but I get a ValueError: <geoprocessing describe geometry object object at 0x000000000D05A5A8

Comment: This is a different question, which probably relates back to not using the correct format.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you gents for your assistance,
I revisited this one after Vince's comment, And I managed to resolved it by using only arcpy (no shapely).

```
 Shape2 = shape(onerow[0])
```

now replaced with:

```
 Shape2 = onerow[0]
```

and then on with the calculations.
The "Polygon with hole" does not seem to be an issue anymore.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know the result of `arcpy.da.SearchCursor(OurCADLAYER, ['SHAPE@'], whereclause)` (I don't use ArGIS) but the function shape of Shapely is for the the GeoJSON-like [Python geo_interface protocol](https://gist.github.com/sgillies/2217756) (conversion of a GeoJSON feature to a shapely geometry)

1) GeoJSON

```py
from shapely.geometry import shape
poly_hole={'type': 'Polygon', 'coordinates': (((0.0, 0.0), (0.0, 2.0), (2.0, 2.0), (2.0, 0.0), (0.0, 0.0)), ((1.0, 1.0), (1.0, 1.5), (1.5, 1.5), (1.5, 1.0), (1.0, 1.0)))}
poly = shape(poly_hole)
print(poly)
POLYGON ((0 0, 0 2, 2 2, 2 0, 0 0), (1 1, 1 1.5, 1.5 1.5, 1.5 1, 1 1))
mapping(poly)
{'type': 'Polygon', 'coordinates': (((0.0, 0.0), (0.0, 2.0), (2.0, 2.0), (2.0, 0.0), (0.0, 0.0)), ((1.0, 1.0), (1.0, 1.5), (1.5, 1.5), (1.5, 1.0), (1.0, 1.0)))}
# or
poly.__geo_interface__
{'type': 'Polygon', 'coordinates': (((0.0, 0.0), (0.0, 2.0), (2.0, 2.0), (2.0, 0.0), (0.0, 0.0)), ((1.0, 1.0), (1.0, 1.5), (1.5, 1.5), (1.5, 1.0), (1.0, 1.0)))}
```

Look at:

- [Is there an existing library for converting ArcGIS Features to Json?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/968/2581)

> ArcGIS 10 has the AsShape function for converting GeoJSON to arcpy
>   geometries, which mimics Shapely's (As)Shape, and arcpy geometry objects
>   implement the **geo_interface** standard (also from Shapely) for
>   getting arcpy geometries back as GeoJSON.

- [arcpy.geometry **geo_interface** and AsShape() function: loss of precision and holes](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/10201/arcpy-geometry-geo-interface-and-asshape-function-loss-of-precision-and-h) (Holes If the polygon has holes, geo_interface generates an error and solution)
- [esri2open](https://github.com/project-open-data/esri2open)

2) as Vince says you can use the WKT format (same for WKB)

```py
wkt = poly.wkt
from shapely.wkt import loads
poly_wkt = loads(wkt)
print poly
POLYGON ((0 0, 0 2, 2 2, 2 0, 0 0), (1 1, 1 1.5, 1.5 1.5, 1.5 1, 1 1))
```